# Onclick Change Image, jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get this to change the image onClick? And then change it back to it's original state (original image)?

```
jQuery('.expand-one').click(function(){
    jQuery('.content-one').slideToggle('fast');
});

jQuery('.expand-one').toggle(function() {
    jQuery('.content-one').slideDown('slow');
    jQuery(this).find("img").css({
        "-webkit-transform": "rotate(90deg)",
        "-moz-transform": "rotate(90deg)",
        "filter": "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1)"
    });
}, function() {
    jQuery('.content-one').slideUp('slow');
    jQuery(this).find("img").css({
        "-webkit-transform": "rotate(0deg)",
        "-moz-transform": "rotate(0deg)",
        "filter": "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0)"
    });
});
```

Virtually I want to change the out the IMAGE ROTATION for the IMAGE SWAPPING.

Thanks,
Aaron

Comment: I don't know if I get you right... Is this what you're looking for?

jQuery(this).find("img").attr("src","new/image/path/image.ext");

Comment: @Connum: I would guess so. I want to swap the current state of the IMG using the onClick Event? Does that make more sense? lol.

Comment: @Connum: One static image within the .expand-one DIV, via HTML. I want the image to swap it's self with a different image when you click on it, and then once you click on it again it goes back to the original image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the image tag to

```
<img class="expand-one" src="WhateverUrl" data-altsrc="AlternateUrl">
```

and have the javascript as

```
jQuery('.expand-one').click(function(){
    var src = $(this).attr("src");
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).data("altsrc"));
    $(this).data("altsrc", src);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QuzKj/)

Comment: This is definitely not doing anything. Do you have a jsFiddle I can refer to?

Comment: Amit... For the life of me, I cannot seem to make it work... I have it set-up to where the image lies within the DIV, expand-one. I need it to swap images and then when clicked again, go back to it's original image. You can view what I am trying to do... Here: http://jsfiddle.net/QuzKj/4/

Comment: Updated http://jsfiddle.net/QuzKj/5/. The selector has to be img as we want to work on it.

Comment: So I cannot have the image inside the a DIV calling out the class, I have to have the CLASS set on the IMAGE?

Comment: No you can, it is just that the selector change a bit. Check the updated fiddle.

Comment: But if I click on the entire DIV with the expand-one as it's class the images do not swap. It is only if I click on the image itself does it swap.